# Why am I unable to print using Interrupt 14?

Tags: c, printing, dos

Here is a question from the good old times ;-)

I wrote an application back in the nineties that is still being used. It is based on MS-DOS and prints to the serial port COM1.
Now there are some printers that can not be printed to. Obviously BIOS does not send the data to the printer. When I initialize the printer in this like this it works:

```
mode com1:9600,n,8,1
dir A:\ > com1:
```

I assume this is no different from what I do in my C program:
Init:

```
union REGS regs;

m_iBaudRate = iBaudRate;
m_iParity = iParity;
m_iDataBits = iDataBits;
m_iStopBits = iStopBits;

    // Init

regs.h.ah = 0;
regs.h.al = getParamByte();
regs.x.dx = getBiosPort();

int86( 0x14, &regs, &regs );
```

Print:

```
regs.h.ah = 1;
regs.h.al = cChar;
regs.x.dx = getBiosPort();

int86( 0x14, &regs, &regs );
```

As mentioned this works an many machines with various printers but not for some. Any hints ?

Comment: What's the SO and its version where you ran the "DOS" commands you indicate? ( **mode com1:9600,n,8,1
dir A:\ > com1:** )

Comment: Basically it is MS-Dos 6.22

Comment: Ok! If on the same SO and PC other printers work (obvious) is not a BIOS problem (Do you verified that?). I remember the mode command uses functions of int 21h to interface all peripherals, but int 21h calls then executes int 14h when a serial is requested (But might be mode doesn't call int 14h). If the printer you have is working with mode and another printers (if you have one for testing) works on the same system with your SW, the issue might be because some kind of acknowledge.

Comment: I'm remembering that I had a similar problem with a cash register using IBM-DOS 6.20. If I remember good I had to use in 21h functions, but is a lot of time is passed and I'm not sure!

Comment: Have you tried using `ah = 3, dx = getBiosPort()` to get the serial port state in `ah`? See [this link](http://www.ousob.com/ng/asm/ng83233.php) for a description of the bits of the return value

Comment: And perhaps you could post the values/code of `cChar`, `getParamByte` and `getBiosPort`, you might have an error in there.

Comment: Are you sure that getBiosPort() returns 0? Try to set dx directly to 0 if you need to use COM1.

Comment: if some printers work with the current code, (and both working and non working printers are connected to the com1 serial port (not a USB port) then the problem is the printer needs more (possibly a lot more) control info before it can print any ASCII characters..

Comment: Have you been able to replicate this problem yourself or are you just basing this on user reports? There could be any number of reasons why a printer might not be working, including many not related to your code. Without a minimal, complete and verifiable example it's not really possible to answer this question.

Comment: The printer works when other programs access it. One oft the working programs uses direct port io.